# JQuery ajax ignores url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got function **tryGetTicket** which must call ajax request at my **loginUrl**. But when I call this function, it ignores my ULR and send get request without **loginUrl**, ie I expect what request will send at http://example.com/sys/login but in reality http://example.com. What's wrong?

```
$(function(){
 var tryGetTicket =
            function (loginUrl, param)
            {
                var ticket = null;
                $.ajax({
                    url: loginUrl,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: param,
                    success: function( response ) {
                        var result = null;
                        //do something
                        ticket = result;
                    }
                });
                return ticket;
            }       

        $("#importDialog").click (function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var alfTicket = getCookie("alf_ticket");
            var ticket = tryGetTicket("/sys/login", $.param({"alf_ticket" : alfTicket}));
            ///...
            }   
        });
```

---

**Answer:**
It work correctly. Thanks for the advices.

```
 $(function(){
 var tryGetTicket =
            function (loginUrl, param, callback)
            {
                var ticket = null;
                $.ajax({
                    url: loginUrl,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: param,
                    success: function( response ) {
                        var result = null;
                        //do something
                        ticket = result;
                        callback(ticket);
                    }
                });
            }       

        $("#importDialog").click (function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var alfTicket = getCookie("alf_ticket");
            var ticket = 
               tryGetTicket("/sys/login", 
                            $.param({"alf_ticket" : alfTicket}), 
                            function(){
                               ///...
                            });
            }   
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `tryGetTicket` will almost always return `null`, because the `$.ajax` call is asynchronous.

There are no `tiket` and `result` variables.

How are you checking which URL is actually called?

Comment: It still won't work, unless you add `async: false` to the `$.ajax` call

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because of the `tiket` typo? :P

Also AJAX calls are asynchronous (thats what the first A is for) so you have the result in the success function and do something with it there.

So in the click function call tryGetTicket as you did now but move all that `///...` stuff in the success function of the tryGetTicket or make a new function and call it out of that success function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var Path =  "http://example.com";
```

now add this variable in url path, like

```
url: Path+loginUrl,
```

Comment: It must be only relative path

Comment: Yes..u r maintaining single domain right..for all your codebase.